# Deriving formula for approximating the derivatives

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

Derive the following formula for approximating derivates and show that it is O(h^4) by establishing its error:

$$
f'(x) \approx \frac{1}{12h} [-f(x+2h)+8f(x+h)-8f(x-h)+f(x-2h)]
$$

I've tried writing everything out with their taylor expansions. Then I get
$$
f'(x) \approx \frac{1}{12h} \left( 12hf'(x) \right)
$$
But I am not sure if im doing the right thing. Any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to go to a high enough order we can see how close the approximation is. Using$$\begin{align}f(x+ch)&\in f(x)+cf^\prime(x)h\\&+\tfrac{c^2}{2}f^{\prime\prime}(x)h^2+\tfrac{c^3}{3!}f^{(3)}(x)h^3+\tfrac{c^4}{4!}f^{(4)}(x)h^4+\tfrac{c^5}{5!}f^{(5)}(x)h^5+o(h^5),\end{align}$$you can show the right-hand side is $f^\prime(x)-\tfrac{1}{30}f^{(5)}(x)h^4+o(h^4)$. (To save you work beside computing the $h^4$ coefficient, note the $f^{(2n)}$ terms will always cancel because $f(x+ch)-f(x-ch)$ is odd in $c$, while the $f^{(3)}$ term cancels because $8f(x+h)+f(x-2h)$ has no $h^3$ term.) The error is $O(h^4)$, making the approximation excellent for small $h$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Where do you get + o(h^5) from in the end? It's not a part of the formula in my book

Comment: @Zebraboard See the [Peano form of the remainder in Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem). See also [little-o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation). At your level, writing $+\cdots$ may be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Write the Taylor expansion of your terms up to fourth order

For example:

$$ f(x+h)= f(x) + hf'(x) + h^2/2 f"(x) + h^3/6 f'''(x) + O(h^4)$$
$$ f(x-h)= f(x) - hf'(x) + h^2/2 f"(x) - h^3/6 f'''(x) + O(h^4)$$
$$  f(x+2h)= f(x) +2hf'(x) + (2h)^2/2 f"(x) + (2h)^3/6 f'''(x) + O(h^4)$$
$$f(x-2h)= f(x) -2hf'(x) + (2h)^2/2 f"(x) - (2h)^3/6 f'''(x) + O(h^4)$$
Plug in the RHS and solve for f'(x) to get the LHS.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. Where do you get + O(h^4) from?

Comment: All the other terms have a factor of $h^4$

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't enough terms to compute the error term. See my answer.